# systemd[1]: realmd.service start operation timed out. Terminating

Tags: centos, systemd

I am trying to put my CentOS 7 in the domain, I put some others and it was normal, but this machine is not working.

follows the configuration of the machine:

```
Icon name: computer-vm
Chassis: vm
Virtualization: microsoft
Operating System: CentOS Linux 7 (Core)
CPE OS Name: cpe: / o: centos: centos: 7
Kernel: Linux 3.10.0-514.26.2.el7.x86_64
Architecture: x86-64
```

I followed the how to put CentOs in the domain when I realized that the realmd service itself is not working.

Follow the "journalctl -xe" log:

```
- Subject: Unit realmd.service has started start-up
- Unit realmd.service has begun starting up.
Jan 04 17:25:27 SERVER realmd [25333]: Loaded settings from: /usr/lib64/realmd/realmd-defaults.conf / usr / lib64 / realm
/realmd-distro.conf /etc/realmd.conf
Jan 04 17:25:27 SERVER realmd [25333]: holding daemon: startup
Jan 04 17:25:27 SERVER realmd [25333]: starting service
Jan 04 17:25:27 SERVER realmd [25333]: connected to bus
Jan 04 17:25:27 SERVER realmd [25333]: released daemon: startup
Jan 04 17:25:27 SERVER realmd [25333]: could not claim service name on DBus bus: org.freedesktop.realmd
Jan 04 17:25:27 SERVER realmd [25333]: could not claim service name on DBus bus: org.freedesktop.realmd
Jan 04 17:26:57 SERVER systemd [1]: realmd.service start operation timed out. Terminating.
Jan 04 17:26:57 SERVER realmd [25333]: stopping service
- Subject: Unit realmd.service has failed
- Unit realmd.service has failed.
Jan 04 17:26:57 SERVER systemd [1]: Unit realmd.service entered failed state.
Jan 04 17:26:57 SERVER systemd [1]: realmd.service failed.
```

Has anyone ever experienced this?

Comment: The `realm list` command will list your Microsoft Domain?

Comment: The problem is that the service itself is not "up":

`$ systemctl status realmd
● realmd.service - Realm and Domain Configuration
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/realmd.service; static; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: timeout) since Mon 2019-01-07 09:31:10 -02; 5h 40min ago
     Docs: man:realm(8)
  Process: 50010 ExecStart=/usr/lib64/realmd/realmd (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 50010 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)`

Comment: I know, and this seems to be a timeout while searching the domain. I just wanted to make sure if there isn't any domain searching issue by suggesting you to run `realm list`. Could you do that?

Comment: I understood, sorry the delay of the answer, I can execute yes, it follows the result:

`# realm list
realm: Could not connect to realm service: Error calling StartServiceByName for org.freedesktop.realmd: Timeout was reached`

Comment: That's weird. And what about `selinux`. Could you please check at `/var/log/audit/audit.log` if there is any `avc` on `realm` and  `realmd` related programs?

Comment: Yes, very strange, it follows the audit log:
has some entries with this filter but it seems all are the same.

Comment: # cat /var/log/audit/audit.log |grep realmd
type=SERVICE_START msg=audit(1546942523.191:67646): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 msg='unit=realmd comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=failed'

Comment: To get a clearer log of what is happening on this AVC, install the `setroubleshoot` ( `yum install setroubleshoot-server`), try to start the service (`systemctl start realmd.service`) and see with `journalctl --since "1m ago"` if you get a more meaningfull log with the `setroubleshoot` prefix, something like "selinux is preventing realmd to use capability XXXX", or "selinux is preventing realmd to use resource XXX"...

Comment: I installed the setroubleshoot-server but I do not know if it worked, the command journalctl - does not only work the journalctl -x and it follows the result of the end of the log:

Comment: -- The result is failed.//Jan 08 11:08:00 SERVER systemd[1]: Unit realmd.service entered failed state.//
Jan 08 11:08:00 SERVER systemd[1]: realmd.service failed.//Jan 08 11:08:00 SERVER polkitd[23451]: Unregistered Authentication Agent for unix-process:56030:3245259479 (system bus name :1.18342, object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale en_US.UTF-8) (disconnected from bus)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@nwildner thank you for your attention but I managed to find the solution on the problem reported above in the CentOS forum, it was only to reboot the machine! Follow the link.

https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=47&t=69338&p=291404#p291404